# Why is Spring @Transactional unreliable with AspectJ?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, aspectj, spring-transactions

TLDR: this project reproduces the issue: https://github.com/moreginger/aspectj-no-tx

Edit: Above now reproduced without jooq i.e. using plain JDBC.

Edit: Spring bug - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28368

---

I've been trying to use AspectJ to weave Spring `@Transactional` for a Kotlin codebase. I've seen it working with both load-time and compile-time weaving (the latter using `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving`). However, when I wrote a test that the transaction would be unwound after an exception something strange happened: the test would *sometimes* fail. It turned out that it always failed on the first test suite run, then the second time around it would *run first* (due to failing the first time) and pass. After much investigation, a "minimal" case in my codebase is (**in the same suite run**):

- Runs a test which calls a method marked `@Transactional` on an `@Autowired` bean.
- Runs a test *in a different class* that calls another method marked `@Transactional` on a different `@Autowired` bean, which will make some changes and then throw an exception. Assert that the changes made aren't visible. This fails.

Then if you run this suite again it runs the second test first due to failing the first time and passes. It continues to run in this order and pass until something else fails or `gradle clean` is run. (Note that to avoid the order swapping you can make the first test also fail).

The same thing happens whether I use load-time or compile-time weaving.

How can this be? Especially with compile-time weaving the transactions have been incorporated into the class files. How can accessing a different `@Transactional` method cause one that we access later to stop being `@Transactional` o_O ? I've verified that simply removing `@Transactional` from the first "fixes" the issue.

Comment: So if you have a minimal example reproducing the problem, where is it? A GitHub link would be helpful. Nobody can debug a wall of text. BTW, my assumption is that your tests are not independent but bleed side effects into each other. In that case, the problem would sit in front of the keyboard. But I need to see for myself in order to be sure, I am just speculating.

Comment: Recap: You had time to prepare your own minimal test case, but did not find the solution and are close to giving up. But you had time to ask a question here. If you wish to get help, you should make the problem reproducible. Or just give up, up to you. Less work for me. Your choice. Just saying _"`@Transactional` is not working"_ and expecting anyone to know why - that is asking a bit too much.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look @kriegaex, it wasn't an easy one to reproduce in isolation but I've created a sample project now. Really interested to see what people make of it!

Comment: Thank you very much. It may surprise you, but I am not using Docker. I would have to install (500 MB download) it and learn its basic usage just so as to be able to use the sample project. Would changing it to using an in-memory H2 be an option? I am an AOP expert, but not a big champ in frameworks (EE, Spring) or fan of setting up lots of RDBMS in order to be able to support users on SO. The 500 GB SSD on my laptop is almost full, too, after using the laptop for 3 years.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem, having installed Docker (which I hope not to forget to uninstall later). But I do not why it happens. I think this is not an AspectJ problem. I do not know this Jooq thingy, but AFAIK you need to explicitly configure it in order to support Spring's declarative transactions. I cannot see such configuration in your project. Could that be the reason why it is not working (or half working, after you remove the transaction from the first service)? Anyway, good reproducer project. I am sure someone else can help you, if I cannot.

Comment: I've now removed jooq from the project and reproduced it with plain jdbc.
I agree it's a weird Spring+AspectJ interaction - I've done more debug and I can see the code going through the correct AspectJ transaction interceptor layers in the failure case, but somehow the configured JdbcTemplate doesn't participate in the transaction.

Comment: I am on the road and cannot check now, but if you don't get help here, at least you have a clean reproducer for a Spring issue. Reproducibility is king. I am almost certain that someone can help you.

Comment: I have tried a similar sequence of transactions in the application's main method. It works as expected. Your problem must be related to Spring testing, which I have zero experience with. I am not assuming any problem with the transactional aspect as such, rather with the test setup. But an experienced Spring user should evaluate that assumption.